# When to use “lorsque” and “quand”

Tags: usage, conjonctions, indications-de-temps

I understand that “lorsque” and “quand” both mean “when” in English but when would you use *lorsque* and when would you use *quand*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Quand* and *lorsque* are interchangeable when they introduce a subordinate clause. The meaning is the same, but *lorsque* is a bit more formal than *quand*, and *quand* is more frequent in spoken French.

> Quand je suis arrivé à la gare, le train était parti. (standard, common in spoken French)
>
> Lorsque je suis arrivé à la gare, le train était parti. (more formal)

Only *quand* can be used for asking a question about time.

> Quand viens-tu manger ?